# How to write a single script enabled java testing application?

Tags: java, testing

I'm trying to finish a task which requires me to write a standalone java application that can be invoked by a single script and run automatically. Java JDK location and other arguments like output path are all needed to be involved in the command line, 'cause as well they also need to be tested. I've no experience of writing this kind of script, can anybody give me some hints? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write some sort of [shell script](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_script) which calls your Java program with the necessary arguments. It could be as simple as one or two lines.

You may find this easier if you package your Java program as a JAR which includes all of its required dependencies.

Comment: Thank you! I think it's the right way to do this. where can I find a simple example, I really have no idea of calling arguments. btw, i'd like to write batch script.

Comment: another question is... can I run a shell script on Windows?

Comment: Re: 2nd question: http://superuser.com/questions/373706/how-can-i-run-a-shell-script-in-windows

Comment: ok, I see that I need Cygwin... how about the 1st question? thx

Comment: It's basically just a file that starts with `#!/bin/bash` and the rest of the file is just what you'd type directly into the terminal. Google for bash script or shell scripting tutorials; there's lots out there.